# How to add span element inside a button in asp?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a sidebar panel with an image and a button.

```
<div class="glyphRow" id="gly_Job" runat="server">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment glyphiconSideMenu"></span>
  <asp:Button ID="btnJob" runat="server" Text="Job" 
    CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnJob_Click" />
</div>
```

I want to make the button size to 100% so that I can click anywhere on the panel item but in order to do that I have to move the image inside button. How can I do that?

Comment: `<asp:Button` is not JS or HTML !

Answer (score 1):

something like that ?

```
<div class="glyphRow" id="gly_Job" runat="server">
  <button ID="btnJob" runat="server" Text="Job" 
          CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnJob_Click">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment glyphiconSideMenu"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to use asp:Button instead of html button

Comment: @neki_1111 You have asked for **html** or **js** answer . not asp answer.

Comment: I think you also need to replace `OnClick` with `onserverclick`, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

`asp:button` is **not** standard HTML, it is an ASP.net Webforms control, that renders HTML.

If you *really* want to keep using `asp:button` use the following javascript to add a click event to the `div`

```
document.getElementById("gly_job").addEventListener(function(){
    //Find the button and click it
    this.querySelector(".btn.btn-primary").click();
});
```

For added user friendliness add the following CSS to indicate the whole `div` is clickable

```
#gly_job {cursor: pointer;}
```

Note: code untested and may need syntax error fixes